# Passing Jagged Array to JSONoBJECT and StringEntity

Tags: java, android, jagged-arrays

I am calling a webservice that would do a post to one of my client database. The method is expecting a sessoionId, and a jagged array. It also return a jagged array. I am having an issue passing the jagged array to the JSONStringer and StringEntity. Below is a simple of my code inside the doinbackground:

```
if(sessionId != "")
            {
                  URL = "http://10.0.2.2:88/Student/Grade";
                  requestPost = new HttpPost(URL);
                  requestPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                  requestPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                  List<String[]> parameters = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                  parameters.add(new String[] {"StudentID","SSN"});
                  parameters.add(new String[] {"StudentLastName", "LastName"});
                  parameters.add(new String[] {"StudentGrade","Grade"});

                  JSONStringer VistAConnect = new JSONStringer()
                  .object()
                  .key("sessionId").value(sessionId)
```

**// I am not sure how to format the jaggedArray in here.**

```
                  .key("JaggedArrayParameters").value(parameters)
                  .endObject();
```

**//Converting the below parameter to a string does not help either.**

```
                     StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(VistAConnect.toString());
                      requestPost.setEntity(entity);
                      httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                      HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(requestPost); 
                      HttpEntity responseEntity1 =  response1.getEntity(); 

                      char[] buffer1 = new char[(int)responseEntity1.getContentLength()];
                        InputStream stream1 =responseEntity1.getContent();
                        InputStreamReader reader1 = new InputStreamReader(stream1);
                        reader1.read(buffer1);
                        stream1.close();
```

**//when I look at the resultFromPost, it failed with the message String did not format properly.**

```
                        resultFromPost= new String(buffer1);

            }
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: define jagged array in this context, with example

Comment: It's expecting student[1][0] = "StudentID" and student[1][1] = "543"

Comment: Here is a better example [["Student"]["123"],["LastName"]["Smith"],["StudentGrade"]["A"]].

Comment: your example is not a valid json. [["Student"],["123"],["LastName"], ... would be, or [[["Student"],["123"]],[["LastName"], ...

Comment: It could be due to my limited programming experience, but I am not sure how to pass the value in parameters StringEntity(parameters)
parameters = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  parameters.add(new String[] {"StudentID","SSN"});
  parameters.add(new String[] {"StudentLastName", "LastName"});
  parameters.add(new String[] {"StudentGrade","Grade"});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters must be built using JSONArray instead of

```
List<String> or String[][] = {new [] String{"example","text"}
};
List<String[]> parameters = new ArrayList<String[]>();
parameters.add(new String[] {"StudentID","SSN"});
parameters.add(new String[] {"StudentLastName", "LastName"});
parameters.add(new String[] {"StudentGrade","Grade"});
```

Instead use this:

```
JSONArray jArray= new JSONArray();
jArray.put(0, "example");
jArray.put(1, "Text");
```